# cURL PHP and request referrer

Tags: php, url, curl

what is default referrer URL which from are coming cURL requests in PHP?Is it customizable?
For example when I make this request..

```
 $curl = curl_init("https://3dsecure.csas.cz/transaction");
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data),
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        ));
```

…what will see the requested script this request is coming from?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Default referer is none. You can set your own via CURLOPT_REFERER option.

CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER is for redirects.